# c# drawing doesn't work right after form Initialized

Tags: c#, initialization, drawing

i tried to draw some boxes right after form is Initialized
however they didn't appeared.
i put the code under the InitializeComponent();
like this

```
    public Form2()
    {   InitializeComponent();
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen);
        System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
       formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300)); }
```

but when i drew them after the form is initialized they worked!
So i thought i should wait a moment and draw the boxes.
Then i put the thread to make the draw function wait for 10ms
In short i modified the code like this

```
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Run));
        t1.Start();
    }

    void Run()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen);
        System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
            formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300));
    }
```

and i succeed
So my question is why i have to wait for a moment to draw something right after the form is initialized?
and is there any way to solve this problem not using thread?

Comment: You are painting when the window is not yet visible.  That happens later, after the Shown event fires.  Another good way to make the rectangle disappear is by minimizing and restoring the window.  Or dragging it off the screen.  CreateGraphics() has the distinction of being wrong 99% of the time.  It is only ever useful if you don't mind losing the pixels.  You only ever not mind when you draw at a very high rate, at least 20 times per second.  Like a game does.  Use the Paint event instead.

Answer (score 1):

I find your question interesting and did some experiments myself. I managed to get it to work in Form1_Paint callback :)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.Form1_Paint);
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen);
        System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = e.Graphics; //this.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillRectangle(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300));
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Edited based on Idle_Mind's comment

Comment: The Paint() event provides a Graphics for you; don't use CreateGraphics.  Change `System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();` to `System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = e.Graphics;`.

Comment: wow ... it works! plus would you tell me the reason why my first code is not working and yours working? i'm curious about it

Comment: Read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) slowly and repeatedly..

Answer (score 0):

using paint event works
plus don't use CreateGraphics instead use e.Graphics